# Python: lmfit : shgo does not accept minimizer_kwargs

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression, lmfit

We are trying to find the global optimum of a minimisation problem. We have tried the basin hopping and shgo (simplicial homology global optimization) algorithm from scipy via the lmfit 'interface'. Using basin hopping, we can succesfully converge and tune the local minimizer to our liking. When we use shgo however, we cannot pass 'minimizer_kwargs' to the local minimizer. Illustration of the problem:

Basinhopping:

```
minner = Minimizer(func, params_instance, fcn_args=(arg),disp=True,niter=200,minimizer_kwargs={'method':'Nelder-Mead','options':{'disp':'True','maxiter':10000}})

result = minner.minimize(method='basinhopping' )

print(result.call_kws)
```

Results in:

> {'niter': 200, 'T': 1.0, 'stepsize': 0.5, 'minimizer_kwargs': {'method': 'Nelder-Mead', 'options': {'disp': 'True', 'maxiter': 10000}}, 'take_step': None, 'accept_test': None, 'callback': None, 'interval': 50, 'disp': True, 'niter_success': None, 'seed': None}

This is as expected, since the options for Nelder-mead are correctly passed on as {'disp': 'True', 'maxiter': 10000}.

Now for SHGO:

```
minner = Minimizer(func, params, fcn_args=(arg),sampling_method='sobol',n=600,minimizer_kwargs={'method':'Nelder-Mead','options':{'disp':'True','maxiter':10000}})


result = minner.minimize(method='shgo')

print(result.call_kws)
```

Results in:

> {'constraints': None, 'n': 600, 'iters': 1, 'callback': None, 'minimizer_kwargs': {'method': 'Nelder-Mead', 'options': {}}, 'options': None, 'sampling_method': 'sobol'}

As you can see, suddenly the 'options' for Nelder-Mead is an empty dictionary. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Savannah-dev1

Comment: Hi, Where do you inform the "result" variable? Without it, I can't tell you why it does not work. You may need a little bit more code for us to help you. :)

Comment: Hi, the result variable was created by using minner.minimize with the method. I have edited the question to make it clearer :)